# Fully Nested ANOVA

Tags: r, statistics, nested, anova

I'm trying to reproduce the example in the bottom of the following page of the NIST:

http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/ppc/section2/ppc233.htm

With Minitab and SPSS it is not an issue but with R I don't get it.

I tried:

```
mydata<-read.csv("mydata.csv",header=T,sep=";")
summary(aov(Measure~factor(Machine)/factor(Operator),data=mydata))
```

But the F values are not correct.

Thanks for your help

PS: Here is the dataset of the NIST (mydata.csv)

```
Operator;Machine;Replicate;Measure
1;1;1;0.125
1;1;2;0.127
1;1;3;0.125
1;1;4;0.126
1;1;5;0.128
1;2;1;0.118
1;2;2;0.122
1;2;3;0.12
1;2;4;0.124
1;2;5;0.119
1;3;1;0.123
1;3;2;0.125
1;3;3;0.125
1;3;4;0.124
1;3;5;0.126
1;4;1;0.126
1;4;2;0.128
1;4;3;0.126
1;4;4;0.127
1;4;5;0.129
1;5;1;0.118
1;5;2;0.129
1;5;3;0.127
1;5;4;0.12
1;5;5;0.121
2;1;1;0.124
2;1;2;0.128
2;1;3;0.127
2;1;4;0.126
2;1;5;0.129
2;2;1;0.116
2;2;2;0.125
2;2;3;0.119
2;2;4;0.125
2;2;5;0.12
2;3;1;0.122
2;3;2;0.121
2;3;3;0.124
2;3;4;0.126
2;3;5;0.125
2;4;1;0.126
2;4;2;0.129
2;4;3;0.125
2;4;4;0.13
2;4;5;0.124
2;5;1;0.125
2;5;2;0.123
2;5;3;0.114
2;5;4;0.124
2;5;5;0.117
```

Comment: We do not have access to `mydata`. Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the model with random terms and how to divide to get the F ratios by using the `Error` term in the formula (I changed Machine and Operator to factors in the data):

```
> summary(aov(Measure~Machine + Error(interaction(Machine,Operator)),data=mydat))

Error: interaction(Machine, Operator)
          Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
Machine    4 0.0003033 7.583e-05   20.38 0.00269 **
Residuals  5 0.0000186 3.720e-06                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: Within
          Df   Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 40 0.000346 8.65e-06
```

Answer (score 0):

The summary of the `aov` function:

```
> summary(aov(Measure~factor(Machine)/factor(Operator),data=mydata))
                                 Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
factor(Machine)                   4 0.0003033 7.583e-05   8.766 3.52e-05 ***
factor(Machine):factor(Operator)  5 0.0000186 3.720e-06   0.430    0.825    
Residuals                        40 0.0003460 8.650e-06                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

As you say in your question `8.766` is different to `20.38` that you expected.

However, this is not an error of the function. This is because of how the `aov` function works. As the documentations says (`?aov`):

> Fit an analysis of variance model by a call to lm for **each** stratum.

Notice the 'each' in the above line. This means that the `aov` function always calculates the F statistic (F value) based on the `variable MSE / Residuals MSE`. As you can see `8.766` is the result of the division between `factor(Machine)` and `Residuals` i.e. `75.83 / 8.65 = 8.766`.

This can be seen in the source code as well if you want to dig a little deeper (type `summary.aov` on the console) where it says:

```
if (rdf > 0L) {
        TT <- ms/ms[nt]
        TP <- pf(TT, df, rdf, lower.tail = FALSE)
        TT[nt] <- TP[nt] <- NA
        x$"F value" <- TT
        x$"Pr(>F)" <- TP
    }
```

And this is also why the `F value` for `factor(Machine):factor(Operator)` is correct.

In case you want to find the F-statistic and the associated probability, of the division between `factor(Machine)` and `factor(Machine):factor(Operator)` just calculate it on your own as:

```
a <- summary(aov(Measure~factor(Machine)/factor(Operator),data=mydata))
```

and

```
> a[[1]]$'Mean Sq'[1] / a[[1]]$'Mean Sq'[2] #which is what you want 
[1] 20.38441
```

The corresponding probability `Pr(>F)`:

```
> pf(20.38441, df1=4, df2=5, lower.tail = FALSE) 
[1] 0.00269263
```